# Add onclick event to disabled field

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, onclick

I am using a form a custom generator. The form is specified in a file, this file gets parsed and HTML elements will be generated by JSF 2.x programmatically, for example HtmlInputText by Apache MyFaces.

In our application we have a readonly user role. For those users we try to make all input options `disabled`. On `input` fields we are setting the html `readonly` attribute, for other elements, which have no `readonly` attribute like `select` fields, we are setting `disabled` attribute.

Unfortunately setting `disabled=disabled` will inactivate all javascript events too. Now, I need to trigger a javascript-function `on click` at a disabled option-field. How can I do this?

Comment: invisible div on top of those select fields, and bind the click to that div, or maybe remove the disabled status make it unchangeable? for example make it stay on the selected option even if you change it with the mouse or keyboard. Just some quick Ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the disabled element in another element that supports the onclick attribute. A good example of this is the `<h:panelGrid/>`

```
   <h:panelGrid style="width=20px" onclick="foo.myBar()">  
      <h:someComponent disabled="true"/>
   </h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, there is much you can do about it.

though there is one, ugly solution to this.

place `position:absolute` non-disabled container over your disabled elements i.e.

```
<select disabled="disabled" >
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
<div onclick="alert('s')" 
  style="width:56px;position:absolute; top:1.7%; left:1.6%;height:18px;" >
</div>
```

where value of top and left for the container depends on the position of the select

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9DTf/)